# find the derivative $\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx}\int^a_x \tan(\tan(t))\,dt =$

Tags: derivatives

Find the derivative: $\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx}\int^a_x \tan(\tan(t))\,dt = $

I tried to take the derivative but I am getting the wrong answer every time.

Comment: Maybe you can show your work so we can see where it is going wrong. Regards

Answer (score 3):

Make use of the fundamental theorem of calculus:
$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\int_a^x f(t) dt \right) = f(x)$$

Answer (score 2):

Hints: (1) Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and (2) $\int_b^a f(x)\,dx=-\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$